# Android how to resize image in byte array format

Tags: android, image, compression, arrays

I have a camera activity. My activity will take a picture and then I have an AsyncTask to save the pic to the device. Here is my code:

```
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    // protected Context applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(CameraPreviewActivity.this);

        dialog.setMessage("gravando...");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {

        try {

            int i =jpeg[0].length;
            System.out.println("byte array size"+i);

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date());

            Random generator2 = new Random(10000);
            int r=generator2.nextInt(99999);
            File cacheDir = getDir(DIRECTORIO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String filename = timeStamp+"-" +r+ ".jpg";
            File file = new File(cacheDir, filename);

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            stream.write(jpeg[0]);
            stream.close();

            long t=file.length();
            System.out.println("file size"+t);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        this.dialog.cancel();

    }
}
```

(This class is a modification from the one in CommonsWare book (Advanced android development)

So the SavePhotoTask receives the image in byte array format (byte[]) and saves it in a file.
What I would like to do is to resize it (under 150K) and then save it if it is possible. I know I could create a bitmap but is there a way to compress the byte array directly? Or anyother class I could use.

This is the code for resizing a bitmap:

```
Bitmap thumbnail=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg[0], 0, jpeg[0].length) 
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.close();
        long t=file.length();
        if(t>Constants.MAX_FILE_SIZE){
            stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);
            stream.close();
            t=file.length();
            int i=50;
            while(t>Constants.MAX_FILE_SIZE && i>=0){
                stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, i, stream);
                stream.close();
                i=i-5;
                t=file.length();
            }

        }
```

is there a way I can create something better and of course using the minimum memory resources. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong, but I think you can't compress already compressed data in JPEG format. If you will compress already compressed data, later it will not be possible do decode those data.
I think you should consider about image re-sizing. You can increase image width and height, and this will increase resulting image file size.